# Mean word length java applet

Tags: java, applet

I have this assignment where the text that the user has input gets analysed into the length of the word and how frequent that length comes up. I have done that, but now I need to calculate the mean length of whatever the user inputs? This is the code I have so far:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class assignment_tauqeer_abbasi extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

    JTextArea textInput;     // User Input.
    JLabel wordCountLabel;   // To display number of words.

    public void init() {
        // This code from here is the customisation of the Applet, this includes background colour, text colour, text back ground colour, labels and buttons 

        setBackground(Color.black);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);

        textInput = new JTextArea();
        textInput.setBackground(Color.white);

        JPanel south = new JPanel();
        south.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        south.setLayout(new FlowLayout(-1));

        /* Creating Analyze and Reset buttons */
        JButton countButton = new JButton("Analyze");
        countButton.addActionListener(this);
        south.add(countButton);

        JButton resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
        resetButton.addActionListener(this);
        south.add(resetButton);

        JButton fileButton = new JButton("Analyze Text File");
        fileButton.addActionListener(this);
        south.add(fileButton);

        /* Labels telling the user what to do or what the program is outputting */
        wordCountLabel = new JLabel("  No. of words:");
        wordCountLabel.setBackground(Color.black);
        wordCountLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
        wordCountLabel.setOpaque(true);
        south.add(wordCountLabel);

        /* Border for Applet. */
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(2, 2));

        /* Scroll bar for the text area where the user will input the text they wish to analyse.   */
        JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(textInput);
        getContentPane().add(scroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    } // end init();

    public Insets getInsets() {
        // Border size around edges. 
        return new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
    }

    // end of Applet customisation 
    // Text analysis start
    // }};
    // Text analysis end
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        if (command.equals("Analyze")) {
            String[] array = textInput.getText().split(" ");
            int maxWordLength = 0;
            int wordLength = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                array[i] = array[i].replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
                wordLength = array[i].length();
                if (wordLength > maxWordLength) {
                    maxWordLength = wordLength;
                }
            }
            int[] intArray = new int[maxWordLength + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                intArray[array[i].length()]++;
            }
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sw);
            out.print("<html>");
            for (int i = 1; i < intArray.length; i++) {
                out.printf("%d word(s) of length %d<br>", intArray[i], i);
            }
            out.print("</html>");
            wordCountLabel.setText(sw.toString());
        } else if (command.equals("Reset")) {
            textInput.setText("");
            wordCountLabel.setText("No of words:");
            textInput.requestFocus();
        }
    }
}
```

How will I go about working out the mean length of whatever the user inputs?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: 1. You should use CamelCase for class names (`AssignmentTauqeerAbbasi`) and fields should normally be `private`.
2. Why not simply add up and store all word lengths and store the number of words entered and divide: `meanWordLength = wordLengthSum/nrOfWordsEntered`?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an assignment, I'll give you some guidance and you'll learn the most by working out the code on your own.  The intuition needed here is that you are creating a program to implement the algorithm defined by its [mathematical notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average#Arithmetic_mean).  The Sigma is equivalent to your for loop with an "addition" operation at each pass in the loop.  Since you have an array of all the words, and you know the length of each word, you need to write code that implements the algorithm:

1. start with a `sumValue` of `0`
2. add each `length` to the `sumValue`
3. divide the result by the size of your array